# Clip area and set canvas background in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am clipping canvas area, at the end i want to set clip to null and then set background to image but it's not working ,

```
canvas.clipTo = null;

var backgrounimage="images/tee.png";
    canvas.setBackgroundImage(backgrounimage, function() {
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Is there any way to restrict user to draw in particular area after setting background image?

Answer (score 1):

This way it works — first clip is set to null then the background is set:

```
var backgrounimage = "images/tee.png";
canvas.setBackgroundImage(backgrounimage, function() {
  canvas.clipTo = null;
  canvas.renderAll();
});
```